# Assign each name stored to a list to the data frame in a another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of data frame, I have a list of names.
how can I assign each name to the data frame ? such as first name to the first data frame, second name to second dataframe?

```
names = ["a","b","c"]
dfs= [df1,df2,df3]


for idx, my_df in enumerate(dfs):
    for i in range(len(names )):
        names [i]= my_df
```

Comment: `dict(zip(names, dfs))`?